# How to show an image on browser in Magento

Tags: php, html, mysql, magento, mysqli

```
      <?php
            $hint = 'dell';

            $sql="SELECT p.`entity_id`, pv.`value` as name, 
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pm.`value`) SEPARATOR ', ') as imagesPath
                   FROM `catalog_product_entity` as p
                   INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as pv 
                     ON pv.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and  pv.`attribute_id` = 71
                   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` as pm 
                     ON pm.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and pm.`attribute_id` = 88
                   WHERE pv.value LIKE '".$hint."'";

            foreach($readConnection->fetchAll($sql) as $orders) {
    ?>

    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/product'. $orders["imagesPath"].''; ?>" alt="" />

    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

The output of this code is

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/media/catalog/product/2/_/2.jpg" alt="" />
```

It shows me just the path of the image but i want an image in output on the browser.

Comment: are there any errors shown?

Comment: No there is nothing to show exept this path.

Comment: Is the path really valid? Did you open the path in another browser tab?

Comment: Yup the path is valid when i open the path on another tab it shows me the image

Comment: Are you sure about that? Make sure that it really shows up on another page.

Comment: yes i'm 200% sure.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation score to post the image